# Redundant export usage?

Tags: module, export, julia

Is there any reason to use "export" in a file (which contains no modules) that will be included in another file later on? I came across this type of export usage when looking at some packages on GitHub, which made me wonder. For instance, consider Foo.jl:

```
# Foo.jl
export foo1

function foo1()
    do something
end

function foo2()
    do something
end
```

Which is included in Bar.jl

```
# Bar.jl
module Bar
    include("Foo.jl")

    other stuff
end
```

Won't the function foo2() be in the scope of Bar regardless, thus making the use of "export" totally unnecessary? I saw this type of stuff in several different packages, and don't really get the reason.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help,

Renato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `export`s are not redundant. These `export`s are not about the scope of `Bar` but rather the scopes of other modules that import `Bar`. If you import the module `Bar` via `using Bar` in another module or in `Main`, the name `foo1` will be public so that you only need to write just `foo1` without qualifiers to access the function `foo1` instead of `Bar.foo1`.

If you remove that `export` statement from `Foo.jl` you will see that you can no longer access the function `foo1` without module name qualification after issuing  `using Bar`. You either have to write `Bar.foo1` or explicitly make `foo1` visible in that module via, for example, `using Bar: foo1` or `import Bar: foo1`.

The `include` statement simply makes Julia evaluate the code in that module so you can think of `Bar.jl` as if it is

```
# Bar.jl
module Bar
    export foo1

    function foo1()
        do something
    end

    function foo2()
        do something
    end

    other stuff
end
```

So the `export` statement exports the name of `foo1` in `Bar` to the other modules that import the module `Bar`.

You can find more information about importing, exporting and module system in the Julia documentation.

> Within a module, you can control which names from other modules are
>   visible (via importing), and specify which of your names are intended
>   to be public (via exporting).
>   https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/index.html#modules-1

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and it actually clears up some other points of confusion I was having too. Thanks a lot!